# Using Reflection to find variable names of non instantiated classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I have been trying to find all the variables of a script through reflection. If a script is attached to the game object or in the scene, then there is no problem getting information about that script, but when I take a script from the project, the below code cannot access any info. It could be something related to Serialization or having to call a constructor at runtime, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
public List<UnityEngine.Object> AllScripts;

[ContextMenu("Test")]
public void Test()
{
    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static ;

    foreach (var aObj in AllScripts)
    {
        Type aType = aObj.GetType();
        var aInstance = aType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        var aList = aObj.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);

        string[] res = Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath, aObj.GetType().ToString().Replace("namespace.","") + ".cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        Debug.LogError( res[0]+" " + aList.Length + " " + aObj.GetType());

        foreach (var aVal in aList)
        {
            Debug.LogError( aVal.Name+ "" +aVal.IsStatic);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just a general note: Maybe you should not use `Debug.LogError` for your output. In some circumstances this is treated as exception and no further code executed .. rather use `Debug.Log` or `Debug.LogWarning`. Are you talking about a `MonoBehaviour` or another class type?

Comment: As to `call a constructor at runtime`: For `MonoBehaviour` you would have to add it to a GameObject like e.g. `var instance = new GameObject("TEST").AddComponent<YOURTYPE>();`. `new GameObject` is valid instantiates an empty GameObject into the scene. For non `MonoBehaviour` class you could either simply use `new` or e.g. the [`Activator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance) for creating instances for dynamic types

Comment: I am using a framework where there are alot of unnecessary logs I cannot comment. That is why I decided to use logerror for readability. Anyway, I want this to work for all scripts, but yes this situation arises for monobehaviour specifically.

Comment: I tried using Activator but to no effect. It is not working for this case. I just tried other class types too...they aren't working either